# Computer doesn't boot with Entertainmen Keyboard 8000?

Tags: usb, keyboard, boot, wireless-networking, hub

I have a Microsoft Wireless Entertainment Keyboard 8000, and when the charger/usb-hub is connected, the computer won't start. All I get is the bios boot screen, and it won't go further. But if I disconnect either the usb-cable or the power-cable to the charger the computer boots normally.

Any suggestions as to what's causing this behaviour? I've tried the charger on two different computers with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced a motherboard BIOS bug which involved scanning for USB at startup.  USB 2.0 hubs affected it.  If I recall, it would time out after 3 minutes, so maybe waiting longer would show if this is the same bug.  I imagine an update to the latest BIOS would fix it, if it is this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plugging them in when the pc is on and making sure the correct drivers are installed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with mine man.. I called MS and they were basically oblivious to the issue. The only solution I came up with was to just use the bluetooth usb dongle and ditch the charging station.

It was rather a PITA. Whats worse is now my keyboard is lagging like hell periodically or repeating characters rapidly while in a delayed state. From what I can tell, the 8000 was canned so I'm guessing they had a number of issues with it...